# Using same custom adapter for AutoCompleteTextView and Spinner

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, autocompletetextview

So I use one adapter for my `Spinner` and `AutoCompleteTextView`, which extends `ArrayAdapter<Object>`. For View-related method, I only override `getView`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
    //I do something with TextView here, but won't affect the problem
    return view;
}
```

Now, both declared like this:

```
            adapterSpinner = new CustomAdapter(
                    this, R.layout.custom_layout_item, objects);
            adapterService.setDropDownViewResource(
                    R.layout.custom_dropdown_layout);  
            spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);


            adapterAutoComplete = new CustomAdapter(
                    this, R.layout.custom_layout_item, objects);
            adapterAutoComplete.setDropDownViewResource(
                    R.layout.custom_dropdown_layout);  
            autoComplete.setAdapter(adapterAutoComplete);
```

The result confusing me:

**AutoCompleteTextView**
Applies `custom_layout_item` to its dropdown View instead, and instead applies a `style` I gave in its element in xml to its TextView/EditText layout. It ignores `custom_dropdown_layout` I've set.

**Spinner**
Applies correctly all of them, its TextView view using `custom_layout_item`, and its dropdown view using `custom_dropdown_layout`. Though it ignores the `style` I gave to it in xml.

Functional, both works fine. But from UI, quite a mess... Why did it happen?